# Angular Translate not displaying Tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have a json file

```
{"card.header.label": "<a href=# tooltip=\"hello Tooltip\">data subject</a>"}
```

With html:

```
<p translate="card.header.label"></p>
```

It displays the word as a hyperlink but the tooltip is not showing. Any idea on how to do this?

I am also doing:

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy( 'sanitize' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<p ng-bind-html="card.header.label | translate"></p>
```

Comment: Tried that, no luck